# Error: Module "./menu-items" does not exist in container

Tags: webpack, webpack-module-federation

Webpack config for 'provider':

```
 new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      ...
      remotes: {
        ...
      },
      exposes: {
        "./api-helpers": "./src/api-helpers",
        "./menu-items": "./src/menu-items",
      },
      shared: {
        ...
      },
```

I am getting this on the consumer:

[image]

Is this related to the hiphen in `menu-items`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My consumer remotes were incorrectly configured:

```
'store': 'store@http://localhost:4019/remoteEntry.js',
'api-helpers': 'store@http://localhost:4002/remoteEntry.js'
```

Changing the second line to the following fixed the issue.

```
'api-helpers': 'api-helpers@http://localhost:4002/remoteEntry.js'
```